# Gatsby Redirects with S3 and Cloudfront for internal and external URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I would like to accomplish 2 things

1. would like to create redirects both 301 and 302 dynamically.
2. would like to redirect to external URL

I have Gatsby version 4.2.0.

I am getting the redirects data from Sanity and I create redirects in **gatsby-node.js**

```
 if (redirects && redirects.length > 0) {
   redirects.forEach((redirect) => {
     createRedirect({
       fromPath: redirect.fromPath,
       toPath: redirect.toPath,
       statusCode: rarseInt(edirect.statusCode),
       force: true,
  });
});
```

Example redirects data from Sanity:

```
[
 {
  _id: 'b6b1a54e-9642-4509-a691-9b183d15b681',
  _createdAt: '2022-01-18T15:25:57Z',
  fromPath: '/test/',
  statusCode: '301',
  toPath: '/services/'
},
{
  _id: 'f8f1c364-0305-4848-9f89-750d8eaadcee',
  _createdAt: '2022-01-19T13:49:56Z',
  fromPath: '/test2/',
  statusCode: '302',
  toPath: 'www.google.com'
} ]
```

I am using [gatsby-plugin-s3](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-s3/), which detects the create redirects and on build it creates: **s3.sls.routingRules.json**, **s3.routingRules.json** etc. inside **.cache** directory.

However I can see that the **statusCode is always 302** and not **301** as set in **createRedirect()**

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: According to the docs, `statusCode`  should be a number. I guess it will have no effect, but have you tried to cast it as a number with `toInt` or similar?

Comment: Yes, I have updated that, but still the statusCode is always 302 for s3 routing rules

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the status code that was always set to 302 within **gatsby-plugin-offline**. Also I wanted to achieve internal and external redirects.

My solution for this is that in **gatsby-node.js** on build time, instead of using **createRedirect()**. I am creating **redirects.json** file after I fetch the redirects from **Sanity**, where redirects (FROM and TO) are **full URLS** (example: https://test.com/test/).

```
const fs = require("fs");

 if (redirects && redirects.length > 0) {
    let r = [];
    redirects.forEach((redirect) => {
  
        let fromPathSplit = redirect.fromPath.split("://")[1].split("/");
        fromPathSplit.shift();
        const keyCondition = fromPathSplit.join("/");
        const toPathSplit = redirect.toPath.split("://");
        const redirectProtocol = toPathSplit[0];
        const urlSplit = toPathSplit[1].split("/");
        const hostName = urlSplit[0];
        const path = urlSplit.slice(1).join("/");
        r.push({
          RoutingRuleCondition: {
            KeyPrefixEquals: keyCondition,
          },
          RedirectRule: {
            ReplaceKeyWith: path,
            HttpRedirectCode: redirect.statusCode,
            Protocol: redirectProtocol,
            HostName: hostName,
          },
        });
    });
    fs.writeFile("redirects.json", JSON.stringify(r), function (err) {
      if (err) console.log("creating redirects.json file error", err);
    });
  }
```

After **redirects.json** is created I am setting it as **RoutingRules** configuration for my **S3 Bucket**

```
 FrontendBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        WebsiteConfiguration:
          IndexDocument: index.html
          ErrorDocument: 404.html
          RoutingRules: ${file(./redirects.json)}
```